# /Zm100 being set by something even though I specify /Zm200

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a large project that I'm trying to decrease the build time by using precompiled headers.

Everything works great in Debug, but my PCH size needed to be increased from the default 100 to 200.

The problem is in release, even if I set the same additional arguments with in Release, I get the following error.
error C1094: '-Zm100' : command line option is inconsistent with value used to build precompiled header ('-Zm200')  C:\MyPath\my_file.cpp

Does anyone have any idea where the -Zm100 is being set?

Here is the text from All Options for the Command Line
/Yu"stdafx.h" /GS- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"../../../../Source" /Zi /Gm /Od /Fd"x64\Release\vc110.pdb" /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_USRDLL" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /GR /Gd /MD /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /Fp"x64\Release\myDLL.pch"

Comment: Is it possible that this is a setting forced by VisualStudio so that a release build has a maximum 75MB PCH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I dug into this deeper, I found that our stdafx.cpp had a specific setup of -Zm300, so when I tried to set -Zm200 on the project I got the inconsistency.

This article helped.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ztc68td.aspx